# Center the second row of a bunch of <li>'s without adding divs?

Tags: html, css

So I have a question that might be relatively simple, but I haven't been able to solve yet.

On my website, I have a  of company logos that is within a div that breaks if you add any other divs for organizational purposes (because the first div is used for css animations and adding any other divs in it causes problems for some reason), which is preventing me from centering the second row's logos beneath the first row. I've been kindly warned about posting links so deleted that. Here is the relevant code (i'm hoping it's complete):

```
  <ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="x" />
            <div><span>Account Management and Product Intern</span></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="x" />
            <div><span>Advisory Board Member</span></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="x" />
            <div><span>Biz. Intelligence and Web Specialist</span></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="x" />
            <div><span>Marketing Manager</span></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>  
          <a href="#">
            <img src="x" />
            <div><span>Marketing Consultant</span></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="x" />
            <div><span>Product Manager/Developer</span></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="X" />
            <div><span>Tech+Data Lead/Advisor</span></div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Due to the sizes of the container and the images, these elements show up as 3 in the first row, 4 in the second. Does anyone have any solutions for this? I tried turning them into inline-block elements, or adding margins, but nothing really worked without specifying a new div for the second row's 4 elements.

Thanks in advance!

*Edit: Deleted link, sorry about that.

Comment: You should refrain from just posting links to your site, include some code or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: There's no policy against linking to a personal or corporate sites per se, however the idea is that you should post your code here because a) many people don't trust random web sites, but more importantly b) if you simply link to the site with the problem without posting the code here, the site in question may be down or gone in the future, or someone might provide an answer here which fixes the problem, in which case future visitors wouldn't be able to fully understand the original issue.

Comment: That's a *lot* of markup, is it all really necessary?

Comment: +1 for adapting your question to what the others have suggested. :)

Comment: @j08691 thanks a lot, that actually makes sense and helps me understand what was wrong with my approach. Fixed as necessary. My thinking was people might find some relevant info in one of the 2 attached .css or the .js so wanted to provide as much info as possible. Regardless, good explanation :)
Re:code verbosity, it's so that I can use a direction aware hover tool that is pretty cool and can be found at http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/ if you're curious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
ul{text-align:center;}
li{display:inline-block;}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UpG5M/

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. I've seen that solution a few times and just tested it, and nothing moved. And they are being applied so they are not being overwritten, checked in Chrome's inspect element. Could it be because the li's are images so text-align isn't helping? I appreciate the attempt though :)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what you wanted.  The above fiddle shows both lines centered, with the appropriate images centered above the text.  What looks wrong in the fiddle?

Comment: It's pretty hard to explain so let me try using an image: http://imgur.com/8zJyBS6 Notice how the second row is left justified rather than centered? That's what I'm trying to fix. The code you gave me was a good idea but didn't work, possibly because it can't factor in image widths? Not sure. 
Does that help? Sorry if I was unclear, it's hard to relay what's in my head through text :)

Comment: What I had should work.  There is obviously a piece missing, but I'm not sure what it is.  text-align:center works on inline elements, and since the li's are now inline-block, it will center them.  If that is not happening, then either the parent does not have text-align:center, or the children do not have display:inline-block, or another style is being applied that is interfering, such has float:left, or position: something.  If you could create a jsfiddle with the relevant CSS, and HTML that would help a lot.

Comment: The magic word was "float". As you correctly guessed, there was an interfering float:left, and taking that out fixed everything! It's strange though, my experience so far has been that Chrome's inspector crosses styles out if they are not being used, and that wasn't happening in this case, which confused me. Anyway, thanks a lot for the suggestion and the follow up, all's right again!

Answer (score 1):

You might try to target the offending logos with the :nth-oftype CSS pseudo-class.

http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: Really good suggestion and I ended up learning about nth of type through this, so thank you for that! The previous person's answer ended up working out though so I didn't need to experiment with this pseudo-class, but you get an upvote for teaching me something new :)

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help after the solution :)